# Spring Boot Deserialize ResponseEntity for REDIS

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, redis, deserialization

When my code try to deserialize ResponseEntity to REDIS i have this error:

nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of **org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity**: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (**missing default constructor** or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

**My Controller:**

```
@Cacheable(value = "restapi", keyGenerator = "customKeyGenerator")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/restapi/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)

    public ResponseEntity<Object> findRestApi(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

        RestModel model= new RestModel ();

        model = restService.findRestById(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(produto, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**My Redis Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory rcf) {

        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(rcf);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new JsonRedisSerializer());

        return template;
    }

    static class JsonRedisSerializer implements RedisSerializer<Object> {

        private final ObjectMapper om;

        public JsonRedisSerializer() {
            this.om = new ObjectMapper().enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(Object t) throws SerializationException {
            try {
                return om.writeValueAsBytes(t);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new SerializationException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException {

            if(bytes == null){
                return null;
            }

            try {
                return om.readValue(bytes, Object.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new SerializationException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(300);
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyGenerator customKeyGenerator() {
        return new KeyGenerator() {
            @Override
            public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... objects) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(o.getClass().getName());
                sb.append(method.getName());
                for (Object obj : objects) {
                    sb.append(obj.toString());
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Someone know what i can do? Thanks!!

Comment: You need to write a custom JsonDeserializer for ResponseEntity.

Comment: Better to cache your model instead of `ResponseEntity`, use `@Cacheable` on service method `restService.findRestById(id);`, rather than controller method.

Comment: @HemantPatel Thank you so much! Your solution works perfectly!!

Comment: @LuisGustavoSouza I'm facing the same issue. Could you please help me how to write custom JsonDeserializer. thanks